# Create and use Object Variable

Tags: apex, lightning

How do I create an "Object" variable with two fields inside and assign value to these fields through this "for":

```
        for(RecordTypeInfo info: Indicador_Clinico__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
        if(info.isAvailable()) {
            //Here i would add the value of the variables "info.getRecordTypeId(), info.getName()"
            //in Object Name and Id fields.

            //myObject.Name = info.getName();
            //myObject.Name = info.getRecordTypeId();
        }
    }
```

I imagined an object variable like:

```
Object myObject = {Name, Id}
```

But I don't think that's how you create it. And if it is not ideal to use variable "Object" what would it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List<Object>` and `List<List<Object>>` to store different object like an array. Here is example

```
string name='Dhanik';
string id='111';
List<Object> myObject = new List<Object>{name,id};
List<List<Object>> objects=new List<List<Object>>();
objects.add(myObject);
integer num1=1;
myObject = new List<Object>{name,num1};
objects.add(myObject);
system.debug('myObject:' + objects);
system.debug('myObject:' + objects[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks! @Dhanik Lal Sahni

Answer (score 3):

It is better to create separate strongly typed Apex class, if you want to use this data in lightning component.

```java
public class RecordTypeInfoObj {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id recordTypeId {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name {get;set;}

    public RecordTypeInfoObj(Id recordTypeId, String name) {
        this.recordTypeId = recordTypeId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
List<RecordTypeInfoObj> recTypeList = new List<RecordTypeInfoObj>();
for(RecordTypeInfo info : Indicador_Clinico__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
    if(info.isAvailable()) {
        recTypeList.add(new RecordTypeInfoObj(info.recordTypeId, info.name));
    }
}
```

In lightning component define the following attribute

```html
<aura:attribute name="listOfRecordTypoInfos" type="RecordTypeInfoObj[]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object without explicitly specifying a type using the **Map<String, Object>** data type. This data type allows you to create a **collection** of key-value pairs where the keys are strings and the values can be of any data type, including other maps or lists

```
Map<String, Object> myObject = new Map<String, Object>{
    'name' => 'test',
    'age' => 2
};
```